# How to read XLSX file of size >40MB

Tags: java, out-of-memory, xlsx

I am using `XSSF` of `apache-POI` to read the XLSX file. I was getting an error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Later, increased the heap size using `-Xmx1024m` for the java class still the same error repeats.

Code:

```
String filename = "D:\\filename.xlsx";
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
   fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

In the above code segment, the execution stops at `XSSFWorkbook` and throws the specified error.
Can someone suggest better approach to read large XLSX files.

Comment: You running it from IDE like eclipse? how did you set memory options? I think your settings might not effected properly.

Comment: yes, I'm using eclipse IDE and made the following changes to it...1)In eclipse.ini edited the -Xmx256M to -Xmx-1024M 2)In IDE window->prefrences->Installed JRE->added -Xms256M -Xmx1024M in default VM arguments. I think it might have reflected in eclipse IDE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

POI allows you to read excel files in a streaming manner. The API is pretty much a wrapper around SAX. Make sure you open the OPC package in the correct way, using the constructor that takes a String. Otherwise you could run out of memory immediately.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file.getPath());
XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
```

Now, reader will allow you to get `InputStreams` for the different parts. If you want to do the XML parsing yourself (using SAX or StAX), you can use these. But it requires being very familiar with the format.

An easier option is to use [XSSFSheetXMLHandler](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.html). Here is an example that reads the first sheet:

```
StylesTable styles = reader.getStylesTable();
ReadOnlySharedStringsTable sharedStrings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(pkg);
ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, sharedStrings, mySheetContentsHandler, true);

XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
parser.setContentHandler(handler);
parser.parse(new InputSource(reader.getSheetsData().next()));
```

Where mySheetsContentHandler should be your own implementation of [XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler.html). This class will be fed rows and cells.

Note however that this can be moderately memory consuming if your shared strings table is huge (which happens if you don't have any duplicate strings in your huge sheets). If memory is still a problem, I recommend using the raw XML streams (also provided by XSSFReader).

Comment: Maybe you could help me with solving this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939669/how-to-interrupt-poi-streaming-reader-after-reading-the-first-line

Answer (score 0):

To complement @waxwing's answer, if the input XLS(X) file is password-protected, you will need to get the plain input stream by wrapping the original file with a decrypting decorator. But first, you will need to open the file as an `POIFSFileSystem`.

So in a nutshell:

```
String pass = "secret";
File file = new File("data/1.xlsx");
    
try (POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(file);
   // wrap in org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentFactoryHelper.getDecryptedStream
   InputStream in = DocumentFactoryHelper.getDecryptedStream(fs, pass);
   OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(in)) 
{
    XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
        
    StylesTable styles = reader.getStylesTable();
    ReadOnlySharedStringsTable sharedStrings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(pkg);
    SheetContentsHandler f = new SheetContentsHandler() {
       // ... your implementation of SheetContentsHandler interface ...
    };
    ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, sharedStrings, f, true);
    XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    parser.setContentHandler(handler);
    parser.parse(new InputSource(reader.getSheetsData().next()));
}
```