# Treat all cells as strings while using the Apache POI XSSF API

Tags: apache-poi

I'm using the Apache POI framework for parsing large Excel spreadsheets. I'm using this example code as a guide: [XLSX2CSV.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java)

I'm finding that cells that contain just numbers are implicitly being treated as numeric fields, while I wanted them to be treated always as strings. So rather than getting `1.00E+13` (which I'm currently getting) I'll get the original string value: `10020300000000`.

The example code uses a `XSSFSheetXMLHandler` which is passed an instance of `DataFormatter`. Is there a way to use that DataFormatter to treat all cells as strings?

Or as an alternative: in the implementation of the interface `SheetContentsHandler.cell` method there is string value that is the cellReference. Is there a way to convert a cellReference into an index so that I can use the `SharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(int idx)` method to read directly from the strings table?

To reproduce the issue, just run the sample code on an xlsx file of your choice with a number like the one in my example above.

UPDATE: It turns out that the string value I get seems to match what you would see in Excel. So I guess that's going to be "good enough" generally. I'd expect the data I'm sent to "look right" and therefore it'll get parsed correctly. However, I'm sure there will be mistakes and in those cases it'd be nice if I could get at the raw string value using the streaming API.

Comment: I wasn't taking `SharedStringsTable` literally enough. I figured all strings would be in that table. Turns out that's not true. In my case the string `10020300000000` isn't in the SharedStringsTable, so that solution of trying to read from that table wouldn't work. So I guess I need to concentrate on using DataFormatter appropriately

Comment: Looks like I should just create my own version of this class: http://www.massapi.com/source/github/76/39/763962266/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.java.html as discussed in one of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318229/date-format-issue-with-poi-xssf-and-sax-event-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue I created my own class based on [XSSFSheetXMLHandler](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/230453d76e6e912dfa22088544488a0a6baf83a2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.java)

I copied that class, renamed it and then in the `endElement` method I changed this part of the code which is formatting the raw string:

```
           case NUMBER:
               String n = value.toString();
               if (this.formatString != null && n.length() > 0)
                   thisStr = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double.parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex, this.formatString);
               else
                   thisStr = n;
               break;
```

I changed it so that it would not format the raw string:

```
        case NUMBER:
            thisStr = value.toString();
            break;
```

Now every number in my spreadsheet has its raw value returned rather than a formatted version.