# Efficient way to read a XLSX file and storing the data in Grails

Tags: excel, grails, groovy, apache-poi, sax

I need to read a XLSX file which contains around 50K rows in 5 sheets and is of about 7MB in Grails.

I need to read the file sheet by sheet and need to store each row to a database table.

but i am getting

```
Java heap space. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Executing action [abx] of controller [abc.xyz.controller]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
        Line | Method
    ->>  198 | doFilter                 in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
```

I had tried increasing Heap space by setting up "GRAILS_OPTS" as

```
GRAILS_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:PermSize=128m -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

but not worked at all.

I came across this question

[How to read XLSX file of size >40MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345146/how-to-read-xlsx-file-of-size-40mb) but no proper implementation is available here.

I tried using SAX for reading the XML from the XLSX file by following way from its how to use doc

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html

Grails controller:

```
//      
//
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

        XMLReader parser1 =
                XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(
                        "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser"
                );
        ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst);

 //
//
```

class SheetHandler.java

```
class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private SharedStringsTable sst;
    private String lastContents;
    private boolean nextIsString;
    private List<String> rowData


    private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
        rowData = []
        this.sst = sst;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                             Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        // c => cell
        if(name.equals("c")) {
            // Print the cell reference
            //System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");
            // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        }
        // Clear contents cache
        lastContents = "";
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        if(name  == "row"){
            println rowData
            rowData = []
        }
        // Process the last contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        if(nextIsString) {
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
            lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
            nextIsString = false;
        }

        // v => contents of a cell
        // Output after we've seen the string contents
        if(name.equals("v")) {
            rowData << lastContents
            System.out.println(lastContents);
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

By implementing the above i am unable to distinguish "Labels" from the "rows of xlsx file". and i am also unable to get the null values of columns.

I am unable to use the XSSFReader properly please help me in solving the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "the document is not proper of XSSFReader"?  that you can not use apache poi to read it?

Comment: @cfrick: Edited my question please check.

Comment: You may be running into some of the GORM/Hibernate performance issues highlighted in this article: http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql   (years old, but still very relevant)

Comment: @AndrewvonDollen: Heap space error occur as soon as the file parsing starts and parsing didn't complete at all and exception occours. I am pretty sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

Shashank you can use the same solution. For skipping null cells, all you have to do is check the tag it is parsing. 
This code coverts xlsx into xml with tags

```
 <r> for row 
 <c> for cell
 <v> for value
```

and format

```
 <r><c t="s" r="A32" s="50"><v>value in the cell</v></c></r> if there is a value in the cell
 <r><c t="s" r="A32" s="50"></c></r> if there is no value in the cell.
```

So, if there is a single row with 8 columns and 3rd and 5th column has no value then the sequence in which it will read the xml will be (Just print variable name in startElement and endElement method)

```
r cvvc cvvc cc cvvc cc cvvc cvvc cvvc r
```

where cvvc denotes

```
<c><v></v></c>
```

So just check if startElement method and endElement method has continous c as name in it, this means it has a null value and then just insert a blank in rowData

```
  rowData << ""
```

also you can skip the label rows by passing an offset parameter to the method and skipping the first offset number of rows.

Hope it helps.